# select all duplicates from a table in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, duplicates

Is there a simple way to select all duplicates from a Postgres table? No need for joins or anything fancy. Everything I find on stack is about joins and duplicates involving multiple fields on a table.

I just need to `select * from table where table contains duplicate entries`

Any ideas?

### Table definition from Postgres:

```
scotchbox=# \d+ eve_online_market_groups

                                                           Table "public.eve_online_market_groups"
   Column   |              Type              |                               Modifiers                               | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
------------+--------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id         | integer                        | not null default nextval('eve_online_market_groups_id_seq'::regclass) | plain    |              | 
 name       | character varying(255)         | not null                                                              | extended |              | 
 item_id    | integer                        | not null                                                              | plain    |              | 
 slug       | character varying(255)         | not null                                                              | extended |              | 
 created_at | timestamp(0) without time zone |                                                                       | plain    |              | 
 updated_at | timestamp(0) without time zone |                                                                       | plain    |              | 
Indexes:
    "eve_online_market_groups_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
Has OIDs: no
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by `fancy`, but you would need to join (at least once) to itself, to find duplicates.

Comment: Do you have what the sql would look like for a sample table to find duplicates? Your answer doesn't help me any

Comment: There can't be an answer at this stage, because the question needs to provide at least a basic SQL table, with column names, structure for any meaningful (working) solution.

Comment: @RobinsTharakan Table deffinition given

Comment: There are two ways to find out duplicates: 1) `select field1, field2,... from table group by field1, field2,... having count(*) > 1` to select duplicating combinations; 2) `select * from (select *, count(*) over (partition by field1, field2,...) as dup_cnt from table) t where dup_cnt > 1` to select all columns.

Comment: Your ID is a sequence and a primary key.  It will never have a duplicate.  Therefore your question is moot.  Your definition of what a duplicate is must first be described

Comment: @vol7ron that's the dumbest response you can give. Of course you can duplicate entries

Comment: Kyle, if you don't understand the comment, then you should be careful about throwing around the word *dumb*. If you need help to understand, you should ask.

Comment: `you're literally an idiot` good luck, Kyle.  When you realize what your question is asking and what you're saying, you will certainly feel ignorant.  You can't have duplicate records when you can't insert duplicate records.

Comment: Thank you, Kyle Adams. I am sorry you think a join is *fancy*.  Your question is very simple (I asked my middle school child, which she answered in 5 minutes); however, you clearly cannot construct a proper question. You have not defined what consists of a duplicate. You struggle in establishing relationships. I hope you will find luck for prosperity, as it seems you lack the technical talent and likewise are lacking in social skills. Good luck in the future, do us proud.

Comment: Kyle, `Deffinition` should only have 1 `f` ;)

Comment: Your repetition of that word... is that what you mean by *duplicate*? 

Comment: Your troll tactics won't work on me. I'm done here. I've reported you ... Not that it matters

Comment: Kyle, please report me :) You realize people are emailing me literally saying "this kid is an idiot" and laughing at how you don't understand what is being asked. Here, I'll report myself - you know I've been asked if you should be banned for your death wishes and inflammatory remarks. You should be happy I don't really care about you. ⚡️

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Something like this might be what you're looking for.

```
  SELECT columns_that_define_duplicates -- SELECT item_id, name, slug perhaps?
       , count(*)
    FROM eve_online_market_groups
GROUP BY columns_that_define_duplicates
  HAVING count(*) > 1;
```